# how to modify grouped data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i would like to modify grouped data in pandas. I wrote a shortcode that doesn't work. unfortunately outside of the loop when I use `gr.get_group('Audi')` the data remains unchanged. How to modify grouped daraframes and how to return from grouped data to dataframes later.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'car' : ["Audi", "Audi", "Audi", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "FIAT", "FIAT", "FIAT", "FIAT"],
    'year' : [2000, 2001, 1995, 1992, 2003, 2003, 2011, 1982, 1997, 2002]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['new'] = np.nan

gr = df.groupby('car')

for key, val in gr:
    val.loc[val['year']<2000, 'new'] = f'new {key}'

gr.get_group('car')
```

I would like to use this method because in each dataframe I want to use a different method to set the `new` column

for example for Audi it will usually be adding a variable, while for BMW I want to use the map function

```py
for key, val in gr:
    if key == 'Audi':
        val.loc[val['year']<2000, 'new'] = f'new {key}'
    elif key == 'BMW':
        pass
        #  here another method
    elif key == 'FIAT'
        #  here another metod
    else:
        val.loc[val['year']<2000, 'new'] = 'UNKNOW'
```

at the end i would like to get a table like dataframe but with filled column `new

Answer (score 1):

Try to `pd.concat` the `val` in each for loop to with `the df_new` like below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'car' : ["Audi", "Audi", "Audi", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "FIAT", "FIAT", "FIAT", "FIAT"],
    'year' : [2000, 2001, 1995, 1992, 2003, 2003, 2011, 1982, 1997, 2002]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['new'] = np.nan
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
gr = df.groupby('car')

for key, val in gr:
    print(key,val)
    if key == 'Audi':
        val.loc[val['year']<2000, 'new'] = f'new {key}'
    elif key == 'BMW':
        pass
        #  here another method
    elif key == 'FIAT':
        pass#  here another metod
    else:
        val.loc[val['year']<2000, 'new'] = 'UNKNOW'
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, val])
```

Probably you can also do this with `df.itertuples` or some other method which I am currently not aware.